# Incompatible type , does not conform to the protocol warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

There is a warning message "*Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'DetailViewController**' *Type 'DetailViewController**' *does not conform to the 'TreatmentSelectionDelegate' protocol*", which is showing in the below coding. Why would be the reason for such warning

```
_rootViewController.delegate = _detailViewController;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your DetailViewController's interface (.h) file, add the last word to your class declaration:

```
@implementation DetailViewController : UIViewController <TreatmentSelectionDelegate>
```

DetailViewController needs to know to conform to the delegate methods you're expecting it to be able to handle.

Comment: I think you mean,                                                   @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <TreatmentSelectionDelegate>
. It works. Thanks.